# Flutter Self signed desktop application

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to distribute my flutter application.
I have created a exe file using the "inno setup compiler".

When users try to install the application it is a untrusted application and requires a certificate.

What will be the best way to create a self signed application so I can distribute the application to users?

I have tried to use the MSIX package from pub.dev but it has multiple errors regarding directories that does not exists and even if I create them it still fails.